# Получить все компоненты Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть сайт, на котором используется Vue - можно ли через консоль получить массив ссылок на все компоненты?

Comment: У слова "ссылка" в IT много значений. Какие ссылки вам надо получить?

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei, указатель на участок памяти, в которой храниться компонент). Вообщем, нужен доступ ко всем компонентам

Comment: @Дмытрык, можно воспользоваться расширением для хрома например, для отладки. В противном случае скорее всего придется самому обходить все компоненты

Comment: @Grundy, там, вроде такого нет. А если есть - можете подсказать, куда смотреть?

Comment: @Дмытрык, там, это где?

Comment: @Grundy, в расширении для Хрома.

Comment: @Дмытрык, там прям вкладка Components есть на которой все компоненты на странице

Comment: @Grundy, 1) Если на сайте используется минимизированная версия vue, то консоль Vue не работает 2) Не могу найти там компоненты, которые расположены по другим путям (если говорить о SPA)

Comment: Думаю речь идет о  [стороннем расширение](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd). Правда для его работы нужно чтобы проект был собран в режиме разработки.